# Extract Characters From Text File In C Programming Language

Tags: c

Create a program to extract (only) the alphabetic characters contained in a text file, and dump them to a different file. The extracted characters must be those whose ASCII code is 32 to 127.

I am not able to solve this, can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    char ch;
    fp1 = fopen("bin.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("text.txt","w");
    ch = fgetc(fp1);
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        if(ch >= '32' && ch <= '127')
            putc(ch,fp2);
        else
            continue;
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indicate what you have done so far.  The first step is to open the file.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes i have done this, post edited, you can see the code.

Comment: Converting the returned value from `int` to `char` in the statement `ch = fgetc(fp1);` throws away important information. Define ch as `int` to keep all the information `fgetc()` provides.

Comment: The while should be: while( (ch=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF ) and ch should be of type int because fgetc() returns and int and also putc accept an int! Moreover the fgetc() before the while must be removed, the else and the continue are useless! Your code reads only the first byte of the file!

Comment: I convert char to int, and edit while statement. but the compiler issue warnings and not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 3 errors in your program. First, you only read the first character from the file. And then you don't check it correctly - see the commented out and replaced line. The third is using a `char` type when `fgetc` returns `int`, which might be `EOF`. In addition, `continue` is not needed when there are no more statements in the loop, and you should check that the files did open.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    int ch;
    fp1 = fopen("bin.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("text.txt","w");
    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
        return 1;                           // bad files
    while((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)         // read a char in each loop
        //if(ch >= '32' && ch <= '127')     // don't test 'char' !
        if(ch >= 32 && ch <= 127)           // test as values
            putc(ch,fp2);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TY, as an afterword: another problem with using `char` is it may be `signed char`. That won't hurt in the range checking in this example, but bear in mind that a `char` with value of, say, 160, would be negative: -96.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of `ch` to `int`, otherwise you may be unable to test `EOF`.  You should test if files were opened successfully.  You only read one character from the file, and your test for ASCII is incorrect. Modify the loop this way:

```
...
int ch;
fp1 = fopen("bin.txt","r");
fp2 = fopen("text.txt","w");
if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL) {
    printf("cannot open files\n");
    exit(1);
}
while ((ch = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= 32 && ch <= 127)
        putc(ch, fp2);
}
...
```